# Failsafe way of listening on a unix-domain-socket

Tags: go, posix, unix-socket

This code works fine on the first run:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "net"
)


func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    udsName := "dummy.socket"
    var lc net.ListenConfig
    _, err := lc.Listen(ctx, "unix", udsName)
    if err != nil {
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("failed to listen(unix) name %s: %v", udsName, err))
    }
    fmt.Println("all is fine")
}
```

But it fails on the second run:

> panic: failed to listen(unix) name dummy.socket: listen unix dummy.socket: bind: address already in use

I could just remove the file before `Listen()`, but this could be a failure, if there is already a process listening on this socket.

Is there a way to detect if there is a process listening on the socket?

Then I could remove the old dummy.socket file, if the old server is dead.

Comment: You have to rely on another process cleaning up, or some monitoring layer like init managing the socket. There no failsafe way to check something like this, because another process could start up between checking and taking action on that check (this is a classic [TOCTOU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use) bug)

Comment: Did you set the `UnlinkOnClose` flag? https://pkg.go.dev/net#UnixListener.SetUnlinkOnClose

Comment: @datenwolf, that supposed `Close()` is being called at all! @guettli You should assume that _if_ you can start it's because there is no other server already running. This is why a process management is delegated to an init system, which tracks the service PID and ensures only one instance of that service is running at any time. The unix socket alone is not enough to track the process lifecycle.

Comment: @datenwolf AFAIK UnLinkOnClose does not handle `kill -9` or a sudden power-outage. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @guettli, no you cannot do anything when encountering SIGKILL, which again is why an external service would be used to monitor the process in production.

Comment: @JimB what is an external system for you in this context?

Comment: Any init or other supervisor process, most commonly systemd right now. You could do some of that management in-process, like create the socket in a way associated with the PID, like with a symlink or directory named after the PID, so you can lookup any running processes yourself if there's never going to be a reason to run it like a service.

Comment: @JimB: While I do agree that service management should be done by a controlling supervisor process, I kind of have the impression, that you're latching onto a question that's different from OPs original problem. I don't think that OP's intention is PID tracking or implementing single instance limiter.

Comment: @datenwolf, The question was for a "failsafe" check to reuse the same socket path. I was trying to emphasize that there is no failsafe way without tracking the PID or external monitoring. There are many ways which are probably "good enough", including just unlinking the socket file, and the OP already mentioned that as an option.

Comment: @JimB: Well, if we're going the *really* obsessively detailed way, then even PID tracking is not a surefire way, since PIDs can be reused as quickly as socket paths, once the supervisor did a wait on its children. (Hence the incentive to have `pidfd`-s, and other stable ways to track processes, such as Bernstein's pipe trick).

Comment: @datenwolf, yes, precisely! Asking for "failsafe" means it cannot be broken, while in most cases you just need "good enough" and let the user sort out when something fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete the unix socket file prior to binding, only 'failsafe' way i know:

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "net"
)


func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    udsName := "dummy.socket"
    os.Remove(udsName) //delete the unix socket file
    var lc net.ListenConfig
    _, err := lc.Listen(ctx, "unix", udsName)
    if err != nil {
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("failed to listen(unix) name %s: %v", udsName, err))
    }
    fmt.Println("all is fine")
}
```